# What is the best way of checking how many elements need to be moved to sort an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have an array [1, 2, 4, 5, 3]. In this array, 3, 4, and 5 are not in the position they'd be in if the array was to sorted. How can I check how many elements are not in their right position?

The fastest way I can think of is to copy the value to a temp array, sort the array and then compare which indexes have different values. That would be an O(nlogn) solution. Is there any way to do it in O(n)?

Comment: What is the point of doing this if the solution involves sorting the array, then you don’t need the answer anymore?

Answer (score 3):

> That would be an O(nlogn) solution. Is there any way to do it in O(n)?

No.

Here is an informal proof.

Suppose that there was an algorithm `A` that could find all elements in an array that are out of position in better than `O(nlogn)`.  Suppose also that `A` tells you what the correct position for each element is.  This means that you can sort the array as follows:

```
    list_of_moves = A(array);
    for move in list_of_moves:
       apply move
```

(There is a deliberate "hand wave" here, because the moves will not be simple swaps.  But there are simple algorithms to do this in `O(m)`.  Consider "clock patience" for example.)

We have that `A` is `O(n)`.  The moving step will also be `O(m)` where `m` is the number of moves ... which is less or equal to `n`.  So we now have a *general* sort algorithm that is `O(n + m)`.  That is the same complexity class as  `O(n)`.

However, there is a mathematical proof that `O(nlogn)` is a *lower bound* for general sorting algorithms.  (See https://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/spring14/Lectures/6-moresorting/sortLB.pdf for a presentation of the proof.)

Contradiction!

Therefore, an algorithm `A` with these properties that is `O(n)` *cannot exist*.

---

The other alternative is that the (hypothetical) algorithm `A` tells you (accurately) which elements are in the wrong place, but not what their correct place is.

I think that is also impossible, but I don't have a proof (right now).

---

Note that this is NOT the same as checking if elements are out of order.  That is easy to do in `O(n)`.

The issue is that the out of order elements can still be in the correct place.  For example:

```
  1, 4, 3, 2
```

The 3 is out of order, but it is in the correct place.  In the fully ordered array, the 3 will be in the position it is now.  The 2 and 4 will be switched.

Comment: I checked the proof at `Bowdoin`.  It all made sense until the the last summation was said to equal `(n/2)*log(n/2)`.  To me that did not make sense mathematically.  The number of repetitions in the `sigma` summation does not seem to be `n/2`.  But I am pretty certain I missed something.

Comment: For the general case, `O(n log(n))` is indeed the lower bound, but in the case of integer values, such as in the example input, `O(n)` solutions are possible, such as radix sort and counting sort.

Comment: Well yea.  But if you are using radix sort you don't "move" elements to sort the array.  My assumption is that this is a general sorting problem and the integers are just an illustration.  Otherwise the question is moot.

Answer (score -1):

you can just make a for loop and check if the next array index value is greater than the one before.

```
int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
{
    if (array[i+1] > array [i])
    {
         x++;
    }
}
```

x will be the number of elements not in order

Comment: This is not the problem that the question is asking about.  See the note at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I think the sort is meant to be ascending and you also assume the first element is correct and you will miss if some element is in the right place but the previous one is incorrect